# Using regex to exclude both directories and file extensions

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I need to be able to exclude some directories and file extensions in a single line using regex. I can get them working individually, but I'm not quite sure how to merge them together.

Directories:
`fileExclusionRegExp: /^(media|node_modules)$/`

File Extentions:
`fileExclusionRegExp: /^(r|build|min)\.js$/`

So what I'm looking for is a one line like `fileExclusionRegExp: /^(media|node_modules)|(min)\.js$/`, but my attempts don't work. Any thoughts? Is there another way to handle this using requirejs and r.js node optimizer?

Update:
I didn't mention it, but for the file extensions I want to to find anything with that suffix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
fileExclusionRegExp: /^(?:media|node_modules|(?:r|build|min)\.js)$/
```

Essentially the same, but with capturing groups:

```
fileExclusionRegExp: /^(media|node_modules|(r|build|min)\.js)$/
```

In all cases note the parentheses relative to the start/end operators: `/^(stuff)$/`.